# Images are not loaded in WAPT Pro

Tags: load-testing, wapt

I am trying to record a web test for an ajax based web application using WAPT Pro. Web site images, css, javascript are not captured by WAPT Pro.

Is there any setting available to record capture the images of ajax web application?

Answer (score 0):

WAPT captures all HTTP requests issued by your browser. By default, css, js and image files are recorded as [page elements](http://www.loadtestingtool.com/help/editing-page-requests.shtml). You can find them on the "Page Elements" tab. Note also that it is highly recommended to clear browser cache before recording. Otherwise some page elements may be taken from the cache instead of loading them. You can select the corresponding option in the "Recording Options" dialog.